# Custom keyboard shortcuts in gedit 3.10 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, gedit

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from version 12.04 to 14.04, now with gedit 3.10. Previously I had managed to customize some shortkeys, e.g. block commenting to Ctrl+r and block uncomment to Ctrl+t (instead of the defaults Ctrl+m and Ctrl+Shift+m respectively). These settings did not survive the upgrade and I'm desperately trying to get them working again.

I've googled a lot on the issue, and the best I can find is listed below. I have run gconf-editor and checked the box "gnome->desktop->interface can_change_accels".

1) Close all running instances of gedit.

2) Open ~/.config/gedit/accels as root (with other editor than gedit, e.g. emacs).

3) Edit the relevant lines in the file, in my case (block commenting):

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/GeditCodeCommentPluginActions/CodeComment" "<Primary>r")
```

and

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/GeditCodeCommentPluginActions/CodeUncomment" "<Primary>t")
```

4) Save changes and close file.

If I look at the accels file (via e.g. the cat command), the changes are there. As soon as I open gedit however, the changes I made to accels are overwritten back to the defaults again. I found other posts with similar issues (the changes to accels are overwritten). Does anyone know of how to fix this to be able to customize the keyboard shortcuts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things -

1. you wouldn't edit ~/.config/gedit/accels as root, it's a user file. Typically any edit to an accels file would require removing the ; from line for it to hold. In the case of gedit doesn't matter, you can't successfully edit that file.
2. To actually change just edit the plugin itself, open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/codecomment.py` in a root text editor for 64 bit install & change there. 32 bit is in i386-linux-gnu

(- at or about lines- 89 - 95, just change the letter(s), leave as `<control>`

Comment: Dear Doug,
Thanks for your reply! This solution (changing the codecomment.py) worked perfectly and was just what I needed!
Thanks!